# How to get exact Sybase DB size in a integer or varchar

Tags: sybase

I am trying to retrieve the DB size of my sybase DB.But everywhere I got this command to see DB size, "**sp_spaceused**".But this command is showing all the information along with DB size.
Below is the output,

```
1> sp_spaceused
2> go
database_name database_size
------------- -------------
mydb         310.0 MB

(1 row affected)
reserved data    index_size unused
-------- ------- ---------- -------
5690 KB  1036 KB 2986 KB    1482 KB
(return status = 0)
```

Here mydb is the database name what I am using.But I want a sybase query or command what will return only the DB size which I can place in a varchar or integer and use through out my .sql DB script.

or,

how can I refine my sybase command output(like grep in unix) and filter out only required output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate both data size and log size. In the query; first part is data part sum  and second part is log size sum.

But, please don't forget I assume that your server is 2k page setup.

```
select convert(varchar(100), (
     select  sum(size) *2 /1024
           from master.dbo.sysusages u
          where u.segmap != 4
            and u.dbid = db_id('MYDBNAME')
        ) + (
     select sum(size) *2 /1024
           from master.dbo.sysusages u
          where u.segmap = 4
            and u.dbid = db_id('MYDBNAME')
      )) as "db_size"
```